# Importing multiple excel sheets with multiple tabs into matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

Hello and good day to all,

I am trying to import some excel sheets having multiple tabs into the matlab. For this I have written small loop but after many tries and adjustments still cant get all the data into matlab. In the source directory I have 15 excel sheets with 8 tabs each containing data in the 52 x 102 cells. The data is in signed form meaning containing positive and negative values.   Here below is the code I was working on and I applied different changes which I found on the internet but no success.

```
srcdir = 'path to the folder';  

srcfiles = dir(fullfile(srcdir, '*.xls'));


for i = 1:length(srcfiles)
[status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(srcfiles(i));

for s = 1:numel(sheets)

[data,titles]=xlsread(srcfiles(i).name,sheets{s});

end
end
```

Right now I am getting this error " Filename must be a string". I even tried to change it to the char to string but still didn't work.

Only once it worked When I instead of giving the path in the source directory i.e srcdir, gave the name of the file directly in xlsread().

Can anybody help where am I doing mistakes?.  Thank you

Comment: `[status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(srcfiles(i));` should be `[status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(srcfiles(i).name);` right after the first `for` statement.

Comment: @Suever I did that also but its giving me this error.   

Error using validpath>getFullName (line 66).

Error in validpath (line 23)
        filenameOut = getFullName(filename);

Error in xlsfinfo (line 45)
    filename = validpath(filename);

Error in excelread (line 23)
    [status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(srcfiles(i).name);

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to specify the full path to the file using `fullfile`. Also, in the outer `for` loop you'll need to use `srcfiles(i).name` instead of `srcfiles(i)`

```
srcdir = 'path to the folder';  
srcfiles = dir(fullfile(srcdir, '*.xls'));


for k = 1:numel(srcfiles)
    filename = fullfile(srcdir, srcfiles(k).name);
    [status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(filename);

    for s = 1:numel(sheets)
        [data,titles] = xlsread(filename, sheets{s});
    end
end
```